# Get current process signal handler php

Tags: php, process

Is there a way to find out in PHP the current handler set for process signals?

e.g.
I am setting `sig_handler` method as the signal handler using the following code:

```
pcntl_signal(SIGINT, array($this, 'sig_handler'));
```

now in the next line I am calling a framework method which internally calls thousand other methods (I presume) and eventually change the process signal handler to something else. This causes my `sig_handler` method not getting executed.

Is there a way that I could check which method is registered as the current process signal handler for a particular signal so that I could help myself debugging?

**LATEST UPDATE:**
After debugging deeper into the library code, I found out that the library function undergoes a blocking RPC call that prevented the signal to be triggered to the process. For further information on the issue, please see [this](http://allaryin.com/blog/2008/10/27/php-signals-while-selecting/) link.

Answer (score 1):

No way I know of to check what the current signal handler is - but since pcntl_signal() is the only way to change the handler then a simple grep of the code should reveal where it is being changed (unless you're using a binary framework like phalcon).